# G++-11 destruction order changed from G++9

Tags: c++, g++, object-lifetime

We have following code(it's more complicated ofc, I tried to make a minimal example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct use_type
{
    use_type(T& v) : value(v) {}
    T& value;
};

template<typename T>
use_type<T> use(T& value) { return use_type<T>(value); }

template<typename T>
use_type<T> use(const T& value) { return use_type<T>(const_cast<T&>(value)); }

template<typename T>
struct printer_helper
{
    void use(const use_type<T>& use) { uses.push_back(use); }
    void final_action()
    {
        for (const auto& use : uses)
        {
            std::cout << use.value.size() << std::endl;
            for (const auto& v : use.value)
            {
                std::cout << v << ",";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::vector<use_type<T>> uses;
};

template<typename T>                                        
struct printer
{
    printer() { helper = new printer_helper<T>(); }
    printer<T>& operator , (const use_type<T>& t)
    {
        helper->use(t);
        return *this;
    }
    ~printer()
    {
        helper->final_action();
        delete helper;
    }
    printer(const printer&) = delete;
    printer& operator =(const printer&) = delete;
    printer(printer&&) = default;
    printer& operator =(printer&&) = default;
    printer_helper<T>* helper;
};

template<typename T>
struct printer_creator
{
    printer<T> operator << (const char*) { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
    using vec = std::vector<std::string>;
    {
    /*vec v1{"abc", "bcd"};
    vec v2{"new", "old", "real"};*/
    printer_creator<vec> p;
    p << "", use(vec{"abc", "bcd"}), use(vec{"new", "old", "real"});
    //p << p, use(v1), use(v2);
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on g++ before g++-11. With g++-11 it's either segfault or trash in the output. Is it UB? And if yes, probably you can tell me, which gcc change makes it fail and quotes from standard if possible?

Live examples:

[g++-10](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wXtilEfC51UrktHA)
[g++-11](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OfupKpCyIfycT6b0)

Comment: [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for `printer` is broken.

Comment: @Jarod42, yeah, but it's not needed here. In real code it exists.

Comment: If it used to work, and doesn't anymore, I would bet that it isn't a breaking change that turned the code UB but rather the code was always UB and the compiler change just made it more apparent. There are a lot of red flags in this code, and its hard to know where to focus.

Comment: @ForEveR This is a rare case where having less code makes the example less minimal. Having glaring bugs that don't affect the problem is bad.

Comment: `= delete` them would be fine then.

Comment: Fixed rule of 5.

Comment: I suggest using `-g -fsanitize=address` when compiling. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/7hhdo6ETM)

Comment: On Godbolt even GCC 10 generates code that crashes at runtime.

Comment: Change `use_type` to have a `T value;` instead of a `T& value;` to stop the *stack use after scope* crasher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
p << "", use(vec{"abc", "bcd"}), use(vec{"new", "old", "real"});
```

You create 3 temporaries

- `printer<vec>` from `p << ""`)
- `vec{"abc", "bcd"}`
- `vec{"new", "old", "real"}`

without sequence between them (see note below), so they may be created in any order.

Only destruction from left to right is correct (so construction from right to left), other order would use dangling reference and is UB. And as you don't have guarantee of order...

Note:
We lose short-circuit by overloading `operator &&`/`operator ||`,
we lose left to right evaluation order by overloading `operator,`

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense. I know, that it's bad to overload operator, , but it's from one library.

Comment: It is even worst to depend of (non-guaranteed) evaluation order.

Comment: Yeah... But it's noted nowhere and c-tor accepts const reference. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 10):

The temporary vectors are destructed at the end of the line where they are created. `p` is destructed at the end of its scope (i.e. after the vectors). As the destructor of `p` uses references to the vectors which are now dangling your code has undefined behaviour.

If it ever worked that was pure "luck" that the vector destructors left the vectors in a usable state.

Comment: It is not the destructor of `p` which triggers the printing (or use dangling reference).

Comment: So, that's just luck, that vectors are destroyed after printer is destroyed? https://wandbox.org/permlink/e1M4R19SDdXoMH6L